# subtract values until given range using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file which looks like this:

```
54.0874 -326.094
56.8374 1241.89
57.5374 1644.74
```

The second value is in degrees and I want to subtract 360 in awk as long as the value is between -360 and 0.

The output I am looking for is:

```
54.0874 -326.094
56.8374 -198.11
57.5374 -155.26
```

I was looking into the awk `while` loop but couldn't find a useful solution.

The only thing I got to work was with several if statements, but I wanted a solution which works in every case.

```
awk '{if($2<=0.0) { print $1, $2 } else if($2>=0.0) { print $1, $2-360 }} else if.......'
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to substract 360 repeatedly until the value gets negative? -- If it is, then it sounds like a mathematic problem

Comment: @Jdamian thanks for your [suggested edit to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6159508). However, I rejected it: `1` alone makes it. Test it in your machine and you'll see the magic :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is a great shortcut for "print"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop to keep subtracting when the column is bigger than `0`:

```
awk '{while ($2>0) $2-=360}1' file
```

For your given file it returns:

```
54.0874 -326.094
56.8374 -198.11
57.5374 -155.26
```

Comment: Man, I am learning a lot of English from you. Thanks, @Tom Fenech, this mak... does it :)

Comment: Hi fedorqui, thank you very, very much. I tried the while loop for about an hour and got nothing to really work. You solve it in basically just 2 expressions. Thank you!

Comment: @Keynaan I am happy to have helped you :) Note I hadn't used the `while` condition in `awk`, I went through `man awk` and found the syntax `while (condition) statement`, then started testing.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an easier way to do it without substracting in a loop. On the other hand it does not work if the degree value is less (or equal?) to -360. Here is a more simple solution:

```
awk '{n=$2/360; if((n=n-int(n))>0) --n; print $1, 360*n}' inputfile
```

or a little bit shorter version (with the famous '1' and simplifications from Jidder)

```
awk '($2-=int($2/360)*360)>0{$2-=360}1' inputfile
```

This calculates the remainder part of the degree and then transpose into the (-360, 0] interval.

Input file:

```
54.0874 -326.094
56.8374 1241.89
57.5374 1644.74
57.9999 -700.11
57.9999 360
57.9999 -360
```

Output:

```
54.0874 -326.094
56.8374 -198.11
57.5374 -155.26
57.9999 -340.11
57.9999 0
57.9999 0
```

I hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Well, I honestly think that the `while` loop is more understandable that this approach. But of course I am not objective, I wrote the other answer. Anyway, +1 for the explanation and a generic way to handle this. Note that the generalisation of my code for values <-360 would be `awk '{while ($2<-360) $2+=360; while ($2>0) $2-=360}1' file`.

Comment: Thx! IMHO `while ($2<=-360)` would be a more precise approach. BTW next time I have to divide something I will not use a loop instead. :)

Comment: @TrueY Should the value for the -360 not be -360 still ? If you were taking OP's `between 0 and -360` to mean not including them then 0 wouldn't be acceptable either.

Comment: @Jidder: A -360 degree is 0 therefore I make the values unique. It seems that this is the goal for the OP anyway.

Comment: Okay :), just checking, wasn't sure exactly what OP wanted.Also the awk could be written shorter as `awk '{x=$2/360;if((x-=int(x))>0)--x;$2=x*360}1' inputfile`

Comment: Last comment :) You don't need the `if` anymore `'awk '($2-=int($2/360)*360)>0{$2-=360}1'` for that new one. Also gonna delete my answer as it's pretty much just a worse version of yours now ha !

Comment: @Jidder: Thx! Simplification added!